# moderncv: Defining new command identical to existing one, with different result

Tags: formatting, moderncv

By trying to define a new command in the `moderncv` package by extending the file `moderncv.cls`,
I have noticed the following:

There is an existing command defined by

```
\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{}
```

Now, if I define a command by myself, in the same file, say

```
\newcommand*{\cvitemtwo}[3][.25em]{}
```

Then, using it in my CV document, it does not behave the same as the command `\cvitem`. In fact, I do not even understand why the usage according to the comments,

> % makes a resume line with a header and a corresponding text
> % usage:\cvitem[spacing]{header}{text}

holds. There must be some additional definition, either in the same file, or in some other file, which specifies the command with the exact name `\cvitem`. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) defines `\cvitem` within [`moderncv.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncv.cls) but *redefines* it depending on the style you choose (`banking`, `casual`, `classic`, `empty`, `fancy` or `oldstyle`). This allows for consistent code within the styles (although there are other ways of achieving this) since the macros being redefined will always exist at that point of loading.

Here, for example, is the formal definition of `\cvitem` as its redefined within [`moderncvbodyi.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvbodyi.sty) - the macros that define the "body" when loading `casual`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

If you want to make something similar to this one, you'll have to copy it after loading the style (which loads the body formatting macros). You can do this with [`letltxmacro`](//ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) or `\NewCommandCopy` (since LaTeX's October 2020 kernel update).